# stack bars by an ordering variable which is numeric ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, stacked

I am trying to create a swimlane plot of different subjects doses over time. When I run my code the bars are stacked by amount of dose. My issue is that subjects doses vary they could have 5, 10 , 5 in my plot the 5's are stacked together. But I want the represented as they happen over time. In my data set I have the amount of time each patient was on a dose for ordered by when they had the dose. I want by bars stacked by ordering variable called "p" which is numeric is goes 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc which what visit the subject had that dose.

```
ggplot(dataset,aes(x=diff+1, y=subject)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill=as.factor(EXDOSE)))  +
  scale_fill_manual(values = dosecol, name="Actual Dose in mg")
```

I want the bars stacked by my variable "p" not by fill

I tried forcats but that does not work. Unsure how to go about this the data in the dataset is arranged by p for each subject

example data

```
dataset <- data.frame(subject = c("1002", "1002", "1002", "1002", "1034","1034","1034","1034"),
                         exdose = c(5,10,20,5,5,10,20,20),
                         p= c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4), 
                      diff = c(3,3,9,7,3,3,4,5)
)


ggplot(dataset,aes(x=diff+1, y=subject)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill=as.factor(exdose)),position ="stack")  +
  scale_fill_manual(values = dosecol, name="Actual Dose in mg")
```

Comment: Unclear sentence : ."But I want the represented as they happen over time."

Comment: It's not clear where time appears in `dataset`

Comment: diff = time on dose p= sequence of dose  exdose=amount of dose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to order your stacked bar chart by `p` you have to tell `ggplot2` to do so by mapping `p` on the `group` aesthetic. Otherwise `ggplot2` will make a guess which by default is based on the categorical variables mapped on any aesthetic, i.e. in your case the `fill` aes:

Note: I dropped the `scale_fill_manual` as you did not provide the vector of colors. But that's not important for the issue.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dataset, aes(x = diff + 1, y = subject, group = p)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = as.factor(exdose)))
```

[image]

**EDIT** And to get the right order we have to reverse the order of the stack which could be achieved using `position_stack(reverse = TRUE)`:

Note: To check that we have the right order I added a `geom_text` showing the `p` value.

```r
ggplot(dataset, aes(x = diff + 1, y = subject, group = p)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = as.factor(exdose)), position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = p), position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE))
```

[image]

Second option would be to convert `p` to a factor which the order of levels set in the reverse order:

```r
ggplot(dataset, aes(x = diff + 1, y = subject, group = factor(p, rev(sort(unique(p)))))) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = as.factor(exdose))) +
  geom_text(aes(label = p), position = "stack")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thank you for your response but I can see that subject 1034 starts with 20 but in the data when p=1 the dose is 5 so it is not in the right order for pt 1034 . 1002 looks correct

Comment: See my edit. We have to reverse the order to stack the bars from left to right according to p.